# Stopped being able to paint on texture after project re-opening

Tags: texture-painting

I'm out of ideas. I'm texturing the crossroad. So I have a material where I combine two textures:

- Tiling the asphalt repeatable texture
- Paint road markup using a separate UV-map

It worked perfectly fine. However I forgot to save image before closing blender and now I have to re-do the job.

**The issue is that having absolutely the same setup of material I cannot see anything being painted any more.** I'm just left-click the mouse and dragging it over a mesh but it takes no effect on the underlying image texture.

[image]

I believe there is some not obvious setup I'm missing. Could you folks point me to the right direction.

Comment: As Christoph says, please share your file

Comment: Hi! I added the details in the comments under Christoph's answer.

Comment: It works for me, I could paint on the surface, note that you've selected a texture for your brush. Then I've saved the image, closed the file, re-opened, and the changed were still here. If the same process doesn't work for you I don't know what's happening...

Comment: Appreciate your help 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to click on the CrossRoad texture node. It MUST be active, before painting.

**After checking you file in Blender 3.5:**
You have to switch to the orthographic mode, then all works like expected and you can also zoom in to paint details.

It seems you can paint only in the perspective mode, when zooming out very far from the object. But this is not how it should work, in my opinion.

Another solution is to subdivide your mesh a lot of times, then it is also possible to paint in the perspective mode. But as soon as you zoom in very close, then the same issue appears again.

So it looks like an program issue to me. Maybe you post the problem as a bug here: https://projects.blender.org/

Best wishes
Chris

Comment: It is currently selected on my example screenshot. But not effect.. It gets automatically selected when you select texture slots on Tools settings on the right hand panel

Comment: On my example it is not selected though.. However I just tested your solution and unfortunately it didn't work..

Comment: Please upload your file with embedded textures. So we can test the issue.

Comment: Please check [saved file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13y9Sa6cIFYhpDjffOHehi6unw7xFiB0l/view?usp=sharing). Actually I managed to concretize issue a bit. When I open saved file and try to paint something on the mesh, nothing happens. But once I'm doing a bit of zoom out, I start being able to paint. I use Blender 3.4.1 Linux 64 build.

Comment: I appreciate your time and help. After some attempts and trials I think I found out the reason of my issue. However I do not understand why that matters. Everything works pretty well if I put camera strictly perpendicular to the plane. Otherwise it's either not possible to paint or possible to paint with the brush of large radius. What I want to suggest you is that I'd update your answer with my findings and set it accepted. What do you think?

Comment: See my updated answer, please.